# Reading non uniform lines ascii data - Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, ascii, readlines

I trying to read a non-uniform lines ascii data, e.g.

```
 4  0.0790926412 -0.199457773  0.325952223  0.924105917  48915.3072 -2086.17061
  73540.4807 10
 4  0.0245689377 -0.805261448 -0.152373497  0.573006386 -39801.696  49084.2418
  16665.3857 10
 4  0.0427767979 -0.0185129676 -0.143135691 -0.989529911  38770.6518
 -70784.7024  32640.6307 10
 4  0.0262684678  0.137741 -0.820259709 -0.555158921  25293.3918 -51148.4003
 -126522.859 10
 4  0.145932295  0.466618154 -0.00805648931 -0.88442218  90951.8483  19221.4234
 -40205.3438 10
 4  0.0907820906  0.584060054 -0.671576188  0.455915866 -78193.2124 -31269.5848
  47260.338 10
 4  0.0794897928  0.654042761  0.537625452  0.532153117  24643.9195  39614.3788
  97184.4856 10
 4  0.0896920622 -0.517384933 -0.609729743 -0.600451889 -17455.9074 -17601.0439
 -13991.5163 10
 4  0.0295554749 -0.53757783 -0.3710939  0.757165368  20106.124 -171013.738
 -14052.1145 10
 4  0.0189505245 -0.773354757 -0.0747623556 -0.629549847 -71468.2726
 -53145.1259  36948.4058 10
```

The problem is that I need read each two lines into one. I am trying using `pandas.read_csv` or `numpy.genfromtxt`, but they read and separete into independent lines. I tried to merged every 2 lines without sucess, because, how you can see, sometimes I have a line separated in 7 and 2 columns, somentimes in 6 and 3 columns. With 9 total columns to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

Put your data in a string, or in a document and manipulate it with python. Then when you have your data as you want you use pandas.

```
string1 = '''4  0.0790926412 -0.199457773  0.325952223  0.924105917  48915.3072 -2086.17061
  73540.4807 10
 4  0.0245689377 -0.805261448 -0.152373497  0.573006386 -39801.696  49084.2418
  16665.3857 10
 4  0.0427767979 -0.0185129676 -0.143135691 -0.989529911  38770.6518
 -70784.7024  32640.6307 10
 4  0.0262684678  0.137741 -0.820259709 -0.555158921  25293.3918 -51148.4003
 -126522.859 10
 4  0.145932295  0.466618154 -0.00805648931 -0.88442218  90951.8483  19221.4234
 -40205.3438 10
 4  0.0907820906  0.584060054 -0.671576188  0.455915866 -78193.2124 -31269.5848
  47260.338 10
 4  0.0794897928  0.654042761  0.537625452  0.532153117  24643.9195  39614.3788
  97184.4856 10
 4  0.0896920622 -0.517384933 -0.609729743 -0.600451889 -17455.9074 -17601.0439
 -13991.5163 10
 4  0.0295554749 -0.53757783 -0.3710939  0.757165368  20106.124 -171013.738
 -14052.1145 10
 4  0.0189505245 -0.773354757 -0.0747623556 -0.629549847 -71468.2726
 -53145.1259  36948.4058 10'''

splitted = string1.splitlines()
result = ""
for index,item in enumerate(splitted):
  if index % 2 != 0:
    result += item+ "\n"
  else:
       result += item 
print(result)

4  0.0790926412 -0.199457773  0.325952223  0.924105917  48915.3072 -2086.17061  73540.4807 10
 4  0.0245689377 -0.805261448 -0.152373497  0.573006386 -39801.696  49084.2418  16665.3857 10
 4  0.0427767979 -0.0185129676 -0.143135691 -0.989529911  38770.6518 -70784.7024  32640.6307 10
 4  0.0262684678  0.137741 -0.820259709 -0.555158921  25293.3918 -51148.4003 -126522.859 10
 4  0.145932295  0.466618154 -0.00805648931 -0.88442218  90951.8483  19221.4234 -40205.3438 10
 4  0.0907820906  0.584060054 -0.671576188  0.455915866 -78193.2124 -31269.5848  47260.338 10
 4  0.0794897928  0.654042761  0.537625452  0.532153117  24643.9195  39614.3788  97184.4856 10
 4  0.0896920622 -0.517384933 -0.609729743 -0.600451889 -17455.9074 -17601.0439 -13991.5163 10
 4  0.0295554749 -0.53757783 -0.3710939  0.757165368  20106.124 -171013.738 -14052.1145 10
```

Or if you read it from a file:

```
data = open('/path/original.txt', 'r')
string1 = data.read()
splitted = string1.splitlines()
result = ""
for index,item in enumerate(splitted):
   if index % 2 != 0:
     result += item+ "\n"
   else:
     result += item
new_data = open('/path/new_data.txt','w')
new_data.write(result)
```

Comment: Thanks , I only added the following in your code. To read as a string I used data = open('/path/original.txt, 'r'), then string1 = data.read(). After to run all your code, I needed to save the string reformated, so I wrote a new file as new_data = open('/path/new_data.txt','w')  and then new_data.write(result). After that I read it using pandas! Maybe you can add that in your answer to be more detailed. Thanks again.

Comment: Did it! I just added a quotation mark missed in your last edition

Answer (score 1):

If me, I would like to do that at this way:

```
import re
with open('data.txt') as f:
    s = f.read().strip()
L = [float(i) for i in re.split(r'\s+', s)]
LL = [L[i:i+9] for i in range(0, len(L), 9)]
print(LL)
```

[[4.0, 0.0790926412, -0.199457773, 0.325952223, 0.924105917, 48915.3072, -2086.17061, 73540.4807, 10.0], [4.0, 0.0245689377, -0.805261448, -0.152373497, 0.573006386, -39801.696, 49084.2418, 16665.3857, 10.0], [4.0, 0.0427767979, -0.0185129676, -0.143135691, -0.989529911, 38770.6518, -70784.7024, 32640.6307, 10.0], [4.0, 0.0262684678, 0.137741, -0.820259709, -0.555158921, 25293.3918, -51148.4003, -126522.859, 10.0], [4.0, 0.145932295, 0.466618154, -0.00805648931, -0.88442218, 90951.8483, 19221.4234, -40205.3438, 10.0], [4.0, 0.0907820906, 0.584060054, -0.671576188, 0.455915866, -78193.2124, -31269.5848, 47260.338, 10.0], [4.0, 0.0794897928, 0.654042761, 0.537625452, 0.532153117, 24643.9195, 39614.3788, 97184.4856, 10.0], [4.0, 0.0896920622, -0.517384933, -0.609729743, -0.600451889, -17455.9074, -17601.0439, -13991.5163, 10.0], [4.0, 0.0295554749, -0.53757783, -0.3710939, 0.757165368, 20106.124, -171013.738, -14052.1145, 10.0], [4.0, 0.0189505245, -0.773354757, -0.0747623556, -0.629549847, -71468.2726, -53145.1259, 36948.4058, 10.0]]

Answer (score 1):

Or like this, since you know there are two lines per case.

Read two lines of input each time through the loop. When the first line is empty this implies no more lines are available in the input file. Each time a pair of lines is read concatenate them having first discarded the line ending from the first line.

Pandas can read a 'csv' file that uses white space in place of commas.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> with open('temp.txt') as input, open('temp.csv', 'w') as the_csv:
...     while True:
...         first = input.readline()
...         if not first:
...             break
...         second = input.readline()
...         r = the_csv.write(first.strip()+second)
... 
>>> df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', sep='\s+')
>>> df
   4  0.0790926412  -0.199457773  0.325952223  0.924105917  48915.3072  \
0  4      0.024569     -0.805261    -0.152373     0.573006 -39801.6960   
1  4      0.042777     -0.018513    -0.143136    -0.989530  38770.6518   
2  4      0.026268      0.137741    -0.820260    -0.555159  25293.3918   
3  4      0.145932      0.466618    -0.008056    -0.884422  90951.8483   
4  4      0.090782      0.584060    -0.671576     0.455916 -78193.2124   
5  4      0.079490      0.654043     0.537625     0.532153  24643.9195   
6  4      0.089692     -0.517385    -0.609730    -0.600452 -17455.9074   
7  4      0.029555     -0.537578    -0.371094     0.757165  20106.1240   
8  4      0.018951     -0.773355    -0.074762    -0.629550 -71468.2726   

   -2086.17061   73540.4807  10  
0   49084.2418   16665.3857  10  
1  -70784.7024   32640.6307  10  
2  -51148.4003 -126522.8590  10  
3   19221.4234  -40205.3438  10  
4  -31269.5848   47260.3380  10  
5   39614.3788   97184.4856  10  
6  -17601.0439  -13991.5163  10  
7 -171013.7380  -14052.1145  10  
8  -53145.1259   36948.4058  10
```